# Android Q Kotlin - API 29: check if image exists

Tags: android, kotlin, android-10.0

This is the code I'm using to save image in Android Q:

```
private var fileName = ""
private fun downloadImage(){
    val folderName = "Funny"
    fileName = "bla_" + dlImageURL.split("/").toTypedArray().last()

    // find out here if this image already exists

    val requestOptions = RequestOptions()
        .skipMemoryCache(true)
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)


    val bitmap = Glide.with(this@DownloadImage)
        .asBitmap()
        .load(dlImageURL)
        .apply(requestOptions)
        .submit()
        .get()



    try {

        val values = ContentValues()
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000)
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, "Pictures/$folderName")
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING, true)
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis())
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName)
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName)
        // RELATIVE_PATH and IS_PENDING are introduced in API 29.

        val uri: Uri? = this@DownloadImage.contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values)

        if (uri != null) {
            saveImageToStream(bitmap, this@DownloadImage.contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri))
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING, false)
            this@DownloadImage.contentResolver.update(uri, values, null, null)
        }

    } catch (e: Exception) {

    }
}



private fun saveImageToStream(bitmap: Bitmap, outputStream: OutputStream?) {
    if (outputStream != null) {
        try {
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 95, outputStream)
            outputStream.close()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

How can I find out if this image already exists in the gallery before I download it? I commented where it needs to be.

I already looked up and can't find out how to get the damn path, it was much easier < API 29

Comment: What is your definition of "already exists"? Exists where? In Glide's memory cache?

Comment: In the folder "Funny" in gallery, someone who know how to do it will see by the code where the images are saved anyway

Comment: I added "in the gallery" to the question

Comment: Try querying the same `MediaStore` `Uri` with your desired `RELATIVE_PATH` and see if you get a match.

Comment: Now I tried your suggestion (when I understood it correctly): val check1 = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.toString() + "/" + "Pictures/" + folderName + "/" + fileName
            if (File(check1).exists()){

Comment: And also: val check2 = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)!!.absolutePath + "/" + "Pictures/" + folderName + "/" + fileName
            if (File(check2).exists()){

Comment: Both don't work

Comment: Sorry. I mean `query()` the `ContentResolver` with constraints that use `RELATIVE_PATH`. [Here](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-q/-/blob/vFINAL/ConferenceVideos/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/conferencevideos/VideoRepository.kt#L47-63) I do that sort of thing, though in my case I am using `DISPLAY_NAME` (though arguably I should be using `RELATIVE_PATH` -- not sure if I tried that or not).

Comment: I dono how to use this, I'm kinda new to JAVA Kotlin and Android in general, will see tomorrow what I can do with it

Comment: @CommonsWare In Android 10, Scoped storage, If I Clear data and try to query the resolver it is giving me that the file does not exist but the file is there in the folder. So, I try to give the READ_STORAGE_PERMISSION and I am getting the file but when I remove the permission I am not getting the file. This happens when I clear the data after saving an image and then try to query the resolver.

Comment: @AmanVerma: Perhaps "clear data" is operating the same as an uninstall+reinstall.

Comment: This is not documented. It is creating a problem because If I want to save the image with the same name, android is creating another image with "(1)" added and it is not opening. How to handle this? I can't find it anywhere not even in your blogs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wrote sample code with ContentResolver.query() method. So I tried with Android Q. Sample is like this:

```
val projection = arrayOf(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH
    )

    val path = "Pictures/$folderName"
    val name = fileName

    val selection = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.RELATIVE_PATH + " like ? and "+ MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME + " like ?"

    val selectionargs = arrayOf("%" + path + "%", "%" + name + "%")
    val cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, selectionargs,  null);

    val indexDisplayName = cursor?.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME)

    if(cursor!!.count > 0){
        // file is exist
    }

    // or you can see displayName 
    while (cursor!!.moveToNext()) {
        val displayName = indexDisplayName?.let { cursor.getString(it) }
    }
```

Comment: In Android 10, Scoped storage, If I Clear data and try to query the resolver it is giving me that the file does not exist but the file is there in the folder. After giving the READ_STORAGE_PERMISSION, I am getting the cursor but If i remove it then I am getting empty cursor.

Comment: Wow, you saved my day bro. Brilliant