# Android Studio (Kotlin) save a given image in given path in gallery 2020

Tags: android, kotlin

In Android Studio I want to save a BitMap to a specific folder in the galery of the android device for example /test_pictures as an image.

The easy ways I found on the internet seem to be all deprecated, so it is not good practice to use those.

Does anyone have an easy example code on how to achieve this in Kotlin?

Answer (score 5):

Kotlin bitmap extension like this:

```
fun Bitmap.saveImage(context: Context): Uri? {
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29) {
    val values = ContentValues()
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000)
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis())
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, "Pictures/test_pictures")
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING, true)
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "img_${SystemClock.uptimeMillis()}")

    val uri: Uri? =
        context.contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values)
    if (uri != null) {
        saveImageToStream(this, context.contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri))
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING, false)
        context.contentResolver.update(uri, values, null, null)
        return uri
    }
} else {
    val directory =
        File(context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString() + separator + "test_pictures")
    if (!directory.exists()) {
        directory.mkdirs()
    }
    val fileName =  "img_${SystemClock.uptimeMillis()}"+ ".jpeg"
    val file = File(directory, fileName)
    saveImageToStream(this, FileOutputStream(file))
    if (file.absolutePath != null) {
        val values = contentValues()
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, file.absolutePath)
        // .DATA is deprecated in API 29
        context.contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values)
        return Uri.fromFile(file)
    }
}
return null
}


fun saveImageToStream(bitmap: Bitmap, outputStream: OutputStream?) {
if (outputStream != null) {
    try {
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream)
        outputStream.close()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
}
```

> val imageUri = YourBitmap.saveImage(applicationContext)

Comment: Thank you! Will test that. And how do I check if such a file exists already? As then I would like it to be overwritten.

Comment: Next to this, should also outputStream.flush() be used, is this better practice?

Comment: Your first question : https://stackoverflow.com/a/60970845/8956604

Comment: Your second question : The flush method of [OutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#flush--) does nothing.

Comment: You should change RELATIVE_PATH not DISPLAY_NAME

Comment: I now have the settings like this;

`
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, testtest)
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, testtest)
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000)
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis())
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, "test/images/")
`

It works when I remove the RELATIVE_PATH, but it would be nice if I can get it in some folder. You know how?

Comment: Is there a problem?

Comment: It is working once I remove the RELATIVE_PATH. Then it is just added to the 'Pictures'. But cannot seem to extent it. It gives no errors/exceptions, I see the uri is null if I print.

Comment: You cannot use test/images/. You must use main picture folder like this : Pictures/images

Comment: Picture/images/ does not seem to work. (withuot the last slash it gives exception) I also tried DCIM, but also in vain.

Comment: It must be Pictures/

Comment: Yes I did so, typo, my excuse, that did nothing. This is how the content values are looking right now:

date_added=1588594002 datetaken=1588594002000 _display_name=testimg title=testimg relative_path=Pictures/Test/ mime_type=image/jpeg

Comment: I do see the pictures under 'Pictures' when sending images without the RELATIVE_PATH set. When I set that for example to /Pictures/Test/, I cannot see the 'Test' folder being generated. So that does not work for me unfortunately.

This is what I see and seems to work https://imgur.com/3Xbh2Zi

Comment: I can see generated the Test folder. https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQM78.png

Comment: Are you using an emulator in Android studio, or where you exactly looking at?

Comment: Yes, I am using an emulator.

Comment: Which emulator are you using if I may ask?

Comment: Emulator Pixel 3 Api 29

Comment: Got it to work. Was running 29 code on 27 so that does not work of course. :)

Comment: You can see if-else clause. Another code is running below 29