# unable to save image to gallery from ImageView in Android

Tags: android

Facing problem in saving image to gallery from webview.....storage permission is granted but it does not work.... i have tried all that i can do...kindly help me

here is the code below

```
private void saveImageToExternalStorage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {
    String root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/ahmed");
    myDir.mkdirs();
    Random generator = new Random();
    int n = 10000;
    n = generator.nextInt(n);
    String fname = "Image-" + n + ".jpg";
    File file = new File(myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists())
        file.delete();
    try
    {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Tell the media scanner about the new file so that it is

    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getActivity(), new String[]{file.toString()}, null,
            new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                }
            });


}
```

And this is the button onClick()

```
cvDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    @Override public void onClick(View v) { 
        anImage = ((BitmapDrawable) ivPhoto.getDrawable()).getBitmap(); 
        saveImageToExternalStorage(anImage); 
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Download successfuly"+anImage.toString(), 
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: Share the logcat.

Comment: no error in logcat

Comment: just image is not saving

Comment: cvDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                anImage      = ((BitmapDrawable) ivPhoto.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

                saveImageToExternalStorage(anImage);

                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Download successfuly"+anImage.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

Comment: this is where i call the function to store image

Comment: Please put that code in your post. Not in a comment. You make it unreadable.

Comment: follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61544118/8956604) That is kotlin but you can convert

Answer (score 0):

```
it is work for me:

    public void onCreate(){

    File path=saveBitmap(bitmap);
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[]{path.getPath()}, new String[]{"png", "jpg"}, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
            /*
             *   (non-Javadoc)
             * @see android.media.MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener#onScanCompleted(java.lang.String, android.net.Uri)
             */
            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);


                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);


                intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
                startActivity(intent);
                // sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(path)));
                startActivity(intent); /** replace with your own uri */
                // finish();
                //  finishAffinity();
            }
        });

    }
    public static File saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        String fileName = "";

        FileOutputStream outStream = null;
        File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/MyImages");
        dir.mkdirs();

        fileName = String.format("%d.jpeg", System.currentTimeMillis());

        File outFile = new File(dir, fileName);
        try {
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);


             bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);

            outStream.flush();

            outStream.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return outFile;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this code to download image from the `ImageView`:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    try {
        val bitmap = imageView.getDrawable().toBitmap()

        var outStream: FileOutputStream? = null
        val sdCard: File = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)
        val dir = File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath().toString() + "/sastana")
        dir.mkdirs()
        val fileName = String.format("%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis())
        val outFile = File(dir, fileName)
        outStream = FileOutputStream(outFile)
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream)
        outStream.flush()
        outStream.close()
        Toast.makeText(this, "Saved Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    } catch (e : Exception) {
        Log.e("qrcode", e.toString())
    }
} else {
    Log.e("qrcode", "permission not granted")
}
```

Comment: Something wrong with your code block, please edit it

Comment: you can check it , correct code now